# How is System.Net implemented?

Tags: c#, system.net

I'm learning networking in C#, and I realized that I'm completely dependent on the System.Net framework for networking (not that this is a bad thing). I don't understand how, using standard language features, without relying on any framework, you can connect to a network via C#.

Comment: So you expect someone to explain all 30+ classes here?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I expect. Not a simple and general explanation of a framework's implementation, like the title suggests, but rather a thorough and extensive explanation of each class in the framework.

Comment: "but rather a thorough and extensive explanation of each class in the framework" --- I don't believe it is not a joke

Comment: That'd be a lot of work (probably days) and doesn't fit the SO character well. The desired answer is more the size of a blog series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like a lot of managed runtimes the underlying code relies on native functionality.  I  could list the Win32 APIs that are used or you could just look at the source :)  I prefer the latter.

[.NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) has been open for about [4 years now](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx).

Comment: Do you maybe know how big it is? Chrome isn't telling me.. So far it's 81 MB and counting.

Comment: Truthfully I would just follow ScottGu's blog explanation for setting up the source service.  Then you can simply debug into it.

Answer (score 1):

The System.NET framework simply provides a managed wrapper around the windows API. If you want to see how MS does it, you can open the Assembly with a decompiler (Reflector or ILSpy) and look at the code.